# Jquery compare two String from different elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I want to compare a select option with text content. can it be achieved. though the strings are same, they don't match while comparing.

```
<div id="dateRange">
          <p>27 Nov 2016_26 Dec 2016</p>
</div>
```

and Select option be like:

```
<select id="dateRangeSelect" onchange="showHideForms(this);"><option value="27 Nov 2016_26 Dec 2016" selected>nov-dec</option></select>
```

in Jquery I am comparing:

```
$("#dateRangeSelect").val() and $("#dateRange").text()
```

though they look same in console output, they dont match in if condition
can some one comment on what might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Try to compare not the  `$("#dateRange").text()`, because it returns also the `p` tag as a text. So change it into `$("#dateRange p").text()`

```js
console.log($("#dateRangeSelect").val());
console.log($("#dateRange p").text());

console.log($("#dateRangeSelect").val() === $("#dateRange p").text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dateRange">
          <p>27 Nov 2016_26 Dec 2016</p>
</div>


<select id="dateRangeSelect" onchange="showHideForms(this);"><option value="27 Nov 2016_26 Dec 2016" selected>nov-dec</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to compare the text inside `p` tag with the value. Also use .trim() to remove any white space

```
($("#dateRangeSelect").val()=== $("#dateRange p").text().trim())
```

Answer (score 0):

use Date parse for comparing dates like this

```
Date.parse($("#dateRangeSelect").val()) === Date.parse($("#dateRange").text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim worked.. thank you it was the extra space